# Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using `@Input()` and from my understanding this component should be able to bind `<experiment [experiment]="experiment.completed"></experiment>` to the component. Here is the hierarchy:

[image]

experiment.detail.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {Experiment} from '../../common/experiment.model';
import {ExperimentsService} from "../../common/experiments.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'experiment',
  template: require('./experiment.detail.component.html'),
  styles: [`
    .experiment {
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: 1px lightgray solid;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  `]
})

export class ExperimentDetailComponent {

  experiments: Experiment[];

  constructor(private _experimentsService:ExperimentsService){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.experiments = this._experimentsService.getExperiments();
  }

  @Input() experiment: Experiment;


  doExperiment(): void {
    this.experiment.completed += 1;
  };
}
```

The above's HTML file:

```
<div class="experiment" (click)="doExperiment()">

    <div *ngFor="let experiment of experiments">
        <div *ngIf="experiment">

            {{ experiment.name }}


            <p>
                {{ experiment.description }}
            </p>

            <p>
                <strong>{{experiment.completed}}</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However when I call it on the experiments.component.html I get the error:

```
<h1 class="align-middle">
    {{ title }}
</h1 >
<p class="align-middle">
    {{ body }}
</p>
<hr/>

<experiment [experiment]="experiment.completed"></experiment>

<hr/>
<div>
    <h2 class="table table-striped">Experiments: {{message}}</h2>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="Message">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" (click)="updateMessage(message)">Update Message</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ExperimentsComponent class 
ExperimentsComponent - inline template:8:12 caused by: Cannot read property '    
completed' of undefined
```

NgModule:

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {ExperimentsComponent} from "./experiments/experiments.component";
import {AboutComponent} from "./about/about.component";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ExperimentsService} from "./common/experiments.service";
import {StateService} from "./common/state.service";
import {ExperimentDetailComponent} from "./experiments/experiment-details/experiment.detail.component";

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            AboutComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            ExperimentsComponent,
            ExperimentDetailComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot([
                {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
                {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
                {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
                {path: 'experiments', component: ExperimentsComponent},
                {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
            ])
        ],
        schemas: [
          CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
        ],
        providers: [
            ExperimentsService,
            StateService
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }
```

Github post [Github Post](https://github.com/drewjocham/TestDemo.git)

Comment: what do you have in `experiment.model` ?

Comment: `<experiment [experiment]="experiment.completed"></experiment>` If your `@Input` is expecting a type of `Experiment` why are you passing in the `experiement.completed` value here? Shouldn't it just be `experiment`?

Comment: Can you post the code for the module? That error normally happens when the child component hasn't been declared for the parent component to be able to use it.

Comment: @JayChase please see updated post

Comment: @filoxo please see updated post and git repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looking at your git project routes I can figure out that much that your `ExperimentComponent` is your parent and the `ExperimentDetail` is the child. So let's start from that. You have gotten your code backwards from what I can see, and that is causing the undefined.

It seems that in this case you want to listen to child -> parent interaction. So let's give that a shot. Instead of `@Input()` you should use `@Output()`. `@Input()` is for parent->child interaction.

So your child component emits events.

Your child-html: `

```
<div *ngFor="let experiment of experiments" (click)="doExperiment(experiment)">
            {{ experiment.name }} </div>
```

Your child-comp:

```
@Output() onIncrement = new EventEmitter<Object>();

doExperiment(experiment) {
    // increments the completed property as you wished
    experiment.completed +=1;
    // here we emit the chosen experiment to the parent
    this.onIncrement.emit(experiment)
};
```

And in your parent component:

```
<experiment (onIncrement)="onIncrement($event)"></experiment>
```

And in your parent comp you get the chosen experiment-object here:

```
onIncrement(value) {
    console.log("val: ", value);
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I am using your second solution and getting `self.parentView.context.doExperiment is not a function` but you put me on the right track. Much thanks.

This is just a learning application so that is why somethings might not make sense.

Comment: I updated the project on GitHub and I am working through it now. Thank  you for your detailed post.

Comment: There are two options I gave you parent -> child interaction (the latter) or child -> parent interaction. If you want to use Input(), you have to change the code and components. In your current setup you need to use Output, since your childcomponent needs to communicate to parent, therefore Output.

Comment: GOT IT NOW, now that make complete sense.

Comment: Good :D I removed the whole input part from the answer, so that you don't get confused. I was a bit unclear myself, I admit. But now the answer should be clear :)